# How to add two textbox value and show in other textbox for all rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]

I have create table in html.It will show like excel sheet.I want to multiply dealer price and Quantity textbox value which show in Total Price. It is applicable for all row.
My code is .....

```
<table id="my-table">
<tr>
   <td>Price</td>
   <td>Quantity</td>
   <td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="quantity" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="total" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="quantity" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="total" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can i do it....

Comment: Sorry,your question is not so clear!

Comment: code speaks more than images. please provide some code.

Comment: what is the code for multiply two textbox values and show in another textbox

Comment: Add function to quantity blur event in that function you need to calculation for what u want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you have a table structure like this:

```
<table id="my-table">
<tr>
   <td>Price</td>
   <td>Quantity</td>
   <td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="quantity" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="total" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="quantity" type="text"></td>
   <td><input class="total" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

After document ready, register onchange event on price and quantity element in whole table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-table').on('change', '.price', calTotal)
                  .on('change', '.quantity', calTotal);

// find the value and calculate it

    function calTotal() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
            price    = $row.find('.price').val(),
            quantity = $row.find('.quantity').val(),
            total    = price * quantity;

// change the value in total

        $row.find('.total').val(total)
    }

});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TwRGM/1/)

Comment: I have a mistake at `.on('change', '.price', calTotal)
                  .on('change', '.quantity', calTotal);`

add '.' before price & quantity

Comment: another mistake to forgot add .val() at `price    = $row.find('.price').val(),
            quantity = $row.find('.quantity').val(),` .I update that

Comment: add a demo page by Navin

Comment: How to sum all total value

Answer (score 0):

else if u use mysql query means its so simple

try to add both in query itself and it ll applicable for all rows

else you can use quantity blur event